# What do you need a read-only property with a constructor that let's you set the values in that property for?

Tags: c#, properties, constructor

How is a read-only property with a constructor that lets you set the values:

```
public class Customer
{
    private int m_id = -1;

    public Customer(int id)
    {
         m_id = id;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_id;
        }
    }
}
```

different from a normal **get, set** property like the following?

```
public class Customer
{
    private int m_id = -1;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_id;
        }
        set
        {
            m_id = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't set the value of the property after the object has been constructed with the former but you can with the latter.

Comment: @CraigW. i.e. An immutable object if done properly through the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members variables set within the object constructor can be declared using the [readonly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword.  This allows the variable to act as a constant (e.g. attempting to change it will generate a compile-time error) but still allow you to set it to a different value for each object instance.  This is a bit of syntactic sugar that can help prevent your coders from accidentally modifying values that are not meant to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The `read-only property` does not allow other classes within the program to set the `property` value. The traditional `property` does.

In this case, the `class` is forcing the programmer to provide an `int` `ID` in the constructor. Having a `public property` would nearly negate this requirement as the programmer could alter the value of `ID` at any time.